# bundle exec irb vs bundle exec rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

This [link](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/what-are-the-differences-between-irb/) is great.

However, there is a problem that I am having that I can not figure out.  There are gems that I set in my `Gemfile` that rails seems not to recognize.

When I navigate to my rails application and run these two commands they give me unexpected results.

```
bundle exec irb
$:
```

and

```
bundle exec rails c
$:
```

gives different result.  The former give more paths (which include paths to gems), and the later less.  I thought it should be the other way around.

And specifically the `bundle exec irb` loads all the gems from the my `Gemfile`.  But `bundle exec rails c` only loads some of the gems from the `Gemfile`.

How do I get rails to load all my gems from the `Gemfile` of my rails application?

Comment: It looks to me like both return the same prompt. Can you please post your `Gemfile` and elaborate on the differences you expect and experience.

Comment: I think this may have had to do with restarting my spring server.  Because once I did that, it worked.